# Entering Australia on a 8115 visa tourist visa

Tags: visas

Hi new to site hoping I can get a straight answer!
We are thinking of entering Australia and applying for a partner visa onshore.
My partner will be entering on a tourist visa 8115 if we apply is he entitled to a bridging visa once tourist visa runs out and more important does the bridging visa give him work rights.
Hopefully someone can help and thank you.

Comment: Are you Australian?  Regardless, if the purpose of entry is to settle in Australia, then you should be asking on [Expatriates.SE].

Comment: 8115 is a work restriction clause on a temporary visa. What is the actual visa? If he gets 'no further stay' as a condition of his visitor visa then you cannot apply for a partner visa.

Answer (score 3):

Bridging visas are granted as a **temporary measure**, valid only while the "main" visa is being processed, and grant the same work rights as the *previous* visa:

https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/010-#

This means that, if your partner was previously on a tourist visa, they will *not* have work rights on that or the bridging visa.